# Experience with Plugable USB Audio Adapter for RPi audio?

Tags: usb, audio

Gday,
I was wondering whether anyone has tried using the Plugable USB Audio Adapter with the RPi. It's this one..http://plugable.com/2014/09/23/plugable-usb-external-audio-windows-mac-linux-chromebook

I'm trying to find a cheap solution for audio into PD, preferably below 10ms latency but not the end of the world if it isn't. If anyone has suggestions for a better solution, that'd be really awesome too!
Cheers,
James

Answer (score 2):

I have one of [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-External-USB-2-0-to-3D-Virtual-Audio-Sound-Card-Adapter-Converter-7-1-CH-/151194286036) running on my rPi for use with [RuneAudio](http://www.runeaudio.com/) and have had no real issues with the card after many months of usage. Just required some initial setup in RuneAudio, and very rarely the mixer levels reset and I need to do a quick 'alsamixer' followed by 'alsactl store' to put the sound levels back up to where I want them. I assume the Plugable you mention is just a little more expensive version of my cheap chinese card ...

Comment: Thanks Phil, that's good to know. I'm pretty interested about whether the mic input is laggy, have you tried a mic or just the output?

Comment: Sorry, because I use it purely for playback, I have not tried the mic output.